# Solr: Comparing result documents using debugQuery=true

Tags: solr

I am trying to compare the document explanations of my query result. I am trying to compare two specific documents pasted below and appearing in the same order in the search results (sorted by score desc):

```
**document 1:**

<str name="26a5d1a2-59d8-4bea-950a-0b49d4fe4319">
0.0031454414 = (MATCH) sum of:
  0.00309655 = (MATCH) product of:
    0.04644825 = (MATCH) sum of:
      0.04644825 = (MATCH) sum of:
        0.04644825 = (MATCH) weight(arr1_searchable_cast_members:drew knight^36.36364 in 6613), product of:
          0.008620962 = queryWeight(arr1_searchable_cast_members:drew knight^36.36364), product of:
            36.36364 = boost
            10.775654 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=35200)
            2.2001117E-5 = queryNorm
          5.387827 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(arr1_searchable_cast_members:drew knight in 6613), product of:
            1.0 = tf(termFreq(arr1_searchable_cast_members:drew knight)=1)
            10.775654 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=35200)
            0.5 = fieldNorm(field=arr1_searchable_cast_members, doc=6613)
    0.06666667 = coord(1/15)
  4.889137E-5 = (MATCH) product of:
    4.4002233E-4 = (MATCH) sum of:
      1.6500837E-4 = (MATCH) product of:
        3.3001674E-4 = (MATCH) sum of:
          3.3001674E-4 = (MATCH) ConstantScore(arr_searchable_cast_members:knight arr_searchable_cast_members:knightley arr_searchable_cast_members:knightly), product of:
            1.0 = boost
            3.3001674E-4 = queryNorm
        0.5 = coord(1/2)
      2.7501397E-4 = (MATCH) product of:
        5.5002794E-4 = (MATCH) sum of:
          5.5002794E-4 = (MATCH) ConstantScore(arr_searchable_cast_members:knight arr_searchable_cast_members:knightley arr_searchable_cast_members:knightly), product of:
            1.0 = boost
            5.5002794E-4 = queryNorm
        0.5 = coord(1/2)
    0.11111111 = coord(2/18)
</str>

**document 2 (having less info)**:

<str name="ebf2334c-3f88-4918-8f36-c44532a773e1">
0.0010389417 = (MATCH) product of:
  0.0020778833 = (MATCH) sum of:
    0.0020778833 = (MATCH) product of:
      0.01870095 = (MATCH) sum of:
        0.009900503 = (MATCH) product of:
          0.019801006 = (MATCH) sum of:
            0.019801006 = (MATCH) ConstantScore(vz_searchable_name:knight vz_searchable_name:knights), product of:
              1.0 = boost
              0.019801006 = queryNorm
          0.5 = coord(1/2)
        0.008800447 = (MATCH) product of:
          0.017600894 = (MATCH) sum of:
            0.017600894 = (MATCH) ConstantScore(vz_searchable_name:knight vz_searchable_name:knights), product of:
              1.0 = boost
              0.017600894 = queryNorm
          0.5 = coord(1/2)
      0.11111111 = coord(2/18)
  0.5 = coord(1/2)
</str>
```

Can anyone please suggest how can I compare these two which gives me an idea of their relevant order in the search results?

Also, the query contains a set of fields with appropriate weights (boost values) specified as per the requirements. For the product corresponding to document2 mentioned above, a particular search field used contains a special character (&). Is that a reason for the difference in the detail structure of the two documents?

Please help.

Regards

Comment: http://explain.solr.pl/help can help you to get a better idea.

Comment: You will find a description of the parameters here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#line-121

Comment: my prefered way to display the explain score information is to use these parameters: wt=xml&fl=*,[explain%20style=nl] when you watch the result in firefox you can minimize the tags in the xml view